# get row wise first and second maximum names

Tags: r

I am trying to get the first maximum and second maximum of a row by its corresponding variable name. Please help me to achieve this.

Dataframe:

```
df1 <-  data.frame(AC=c(1.463437e-04,1.023486e-04,1.584040e-05 ),
                   BAT = c(6.555388e-05,5.471379e-01,6.025364e-06),
                   REC = c(6.541157e-05,9.590567e-05,1.581244e-01))
```

Expected Output:

```
       AC                       BAT          REC         First_Max  Second_Max    
1   1.463437e-04             6.555388e-05 6.541157e-05      AC        REC
2   1.023486e-04             5.471379e-01 9.590567e-05      BAT       AC
3   1.584040e-05             6.025364e-06 1.581244e-01      REC       AC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `max.col` to find the column index of max value for each row ('j1'), `replace` the max value with `-Inf` and get the index again ('j2') to create the columns

```
j1 <- max.col(df1, 'first')
j2 <- max.col(replace(df1, cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), j1), -Inf), 'first')
transform(df1, First_Max = names(df1)[j1], Second_Max = names(df1)[j2])
#            AC          BAT          REC First_Max Second_Max
#1 0.0001463437 6.555388e-05 6.541157e-05        AC        BAT
#2 0.0001023486 5.471379e-01 9.590567e-05       BAT         AC
#3 0.0000158404 6.025364e-06 1.581244e-01       REC         AC
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `order` function to get the order of the values and get the corresponding names from the column names (`colnames`).

To iterate over the rows use `apply(df1, 1, function)`.

I put all this into a one-liner:

```
(df1 <- setNames(cbind(df1, t( # cbind to add the two result columns
  apply(df1, 1, function(x) { # apply to iterate over the rows of the data.frame
    colnames(df1)[order(x, decreasing = T)][1:2] # get the column names into the decreasing order of their values and select only the first two columns
  })
)), c(colnames(df1), "First_Max", "Second_Max"))) # add the correct names for the two extra columns
```

```
            AC          BAT          REC First_Max Second_Max
1 0.0001463437 6.555388e-05 6.541157e-05        AC        BAT
2 0.0001023486 5.471379e-01 9.590567e-05       BAT         AC
3 0.0000158404 6.025364e-06 1.581244e-01       REC         AC
```

Comment: Just curious as how this could be done in tidyverse, possibly with map or c_across?

Comment: @MegPophealth it's a bit too long for a comment so I have posted a separate answer. You can use `c_across` but with only three variables `c` may suffice. As for `map`, it's often not so easy to use with `rowwise` (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse solution:

```
smax <- function(...) {
    order(..., decreasing = T)[2]
}

df1 %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(First_Max = colnames(.)[which.max(c(AC, BAT, REC))],
           Second_Max = colnames(.)[smax(c(AC, BAT, REC))])
```